# Android WebView- PopUp background is Transparent

Tags: android, webview, background, popup

I have loaded a WebView in my android app:

```
webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
String url = UrlConstants.URL_CITY;
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}
```

But every popUp that is of the website has a transparent background  as shown:
[image: PopUp with transparent background]

I've tried many urls as well: [One being this](http://www.topuniversities.com/universities/insead-france/undergrad)

Anyone help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Wrap in LinearLayout with white background

Comment: It is already wrapped. Its just all pop-ups are transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when adding WebView at runtime using `addView`. Turns out you need to use the `addView` overload specifying `LayoutParams` with `MATCH_PARENT`. Failing to do so would break side menus and pop-up on some web pages. Really nasty bug if you ask me.